# How to get a Woocommerce order by meta_value in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am building a custom Wordpress plugin to integrate with Woocommerce Orders. This plugin receives a `string` as input. Upon receiving this string input, the plugin must search Woocommerce for an order that matches the passed in value. The Woocommerce Orders have a custom field  `my_number` which stores the values I am searching. I read about `WP_Query` class. I read about `get_posts` function. Both takes a list of `args` as a parameter. All these do not answer my problem. The problem is that running queries using all these Wordpress built-in capabilities are not returning a result! What is fun to me is that if I use the same `meta_key` on a normal Wordpress post, I do get a result back. So, why am I not getting the same result back on a Wocommerce Order. You will see, I have tried even to remove `post_type` filter and all other fields and only left the `meta_key`. This is just one example:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'my_number',
);
    
$posts = get_posts( $args );
    
foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    return ("<pre>".print_r( $post,true)."</pre>");
}
```

So, my question is how to a search an Order in Woocomerce Wordpress using the existing functionalities.

I can see the record in MySQL when I run

```
SELECT * FROM `wordpressTable_postmeta` WHERE meta_key = 'my_number'
```

Attached screenshot shows this order, with the custom field.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I came across this article. To query Woocommerce order, you need to use the Woocomerce class `WC_Order_Query`.

https://pluginrepublic.com/querying-woocommerce-orders/

Now my fixed query looks like this and it is returning something:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'my_number',
);
    
$query = new WC_Order_Query( $args );
$orders = $query->get_orders();
    
foreach ( $orders as $order ) {
    return ("<pre>".print_r( $order,true)."</pre>");
}
```